# undefined method 'add_acts_as_authentic_module'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, authlogic

i've added code

```
config.gem "authlogic-oauth", :lib => "authlogic_oauth"
```

to the environment.rb file in my app and got error

```
undefined method 'add_acts_as_authentic_module' for ActiveRecord::Base::Class
```

is there any solution to solve it?

Comment: I'm using bundler on 2.3.5 and getting the same error. Any know fix?

    gem 'authlogic', '2.1.3'
    gem 'oauth', '0.3.6'
    gem 'authlogic-oauth', '1.0.8', :require => 'authlogic_oauth'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you include the authlogic main-gem?

Maybe this helps you:

http://github.com/tsechingho/authlogic_bundle/issues/unreads#issue/3

Comment: of course! This error is displayed when i'm adding authlogic-oauth, but when i'm deleting it - looks good.

Comment: See the url above.. Maybe it helps?

Answer (score 1):

same problem on rails 3.0.0.beta3 with authlogic-openid

fix from: 
http://futureadapter.com/2009/11/13/authlogic-plugin-errorfix/

this code should be inside this file (mine path pasted):
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/authlogic-oid-1.0.4/lib/authlogic_openid.rb

code:

```
if ActiveRecord::Base.respond_to?(:add_acts_as_authentic_module)
  ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, AuthlogicOpenid::ActsAsAuthentic)
  Authlogic::Session::Base.send(:include, AuthlogicOpenid::Session)
end
```

Comment: This link is also broken.  Here's a cached version: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://futureadapter.com/2009/11/13/authlogic-plugin-errorfix/

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem but it was resolved when I removed the plugin version of Authlogic and included the gem via environment.rb.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error, too, but the above didn't fix it for me.  After digging some more, it turns out I had v2.1.5 of authlogic specified in the environment.rb but only 2.1.3 was installed on the server.  rake gems:install failed with the same error.  Once I installed the 2.1.5 gem directly, everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3, I resolved this issue by explicitly depending on `authlogic '~>2.1.6'` *before* any authlogic plugins in the Gemfile.  Magically went away.